# Automatically reload the message left in svn-commit.tmp when retrying a failed commit?

Tags: svn

Hallo,

this scenario happens to me often: I try to check in with `svn commit`, but for some reason the commit fails (because of conflict, locked files or whatnot). My commit message gets stored in `svn-commit.tmp`. I fix the problem and try to check in again. I now have to enter the commit message from scratch. Wouldn't it be great if svn instead could load the message left in `svn-commit.tmp`? Is there any way to make this happen?

It would be a bonus if it was possible to avoid the trails of `svn-commit.tmp` files somehow.

Answer (score 9):

I don't think there's any automated solution built into svn, but you can always invoke `svn commit -F svn-commit.tmp`. Most of the time I use my editor to copy the message I had typed from `svn-commit.tmp` to the new window.

You could make an editor script or a command-line script which would check for the presence of `svn-commit.tmp` and, if found, pass it as argument and delete it after a successful commit.

Comment: It would actually be slightly more complicated than this as, if you don't delete your tmp commit files, they auto-increment in number like svn-commit.2.tmp, svn-commit.3.tmp, etc, you either need to make sure it's always wiped out or gets the latest.  I need something like too.